# Why Javascript XMLHttpRequest octet-stream MIME type returns the response as string?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I tried to obtain gltf binary file with `XMLHttpRequest`. This is the code I tried.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","THE ADDRESS",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function (v) {
    resolve(xhr.response); // xhr.response must be ArrayBuffer but xhr.response is string
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    reject(e);
};
xhr.send();
```

As per the code above, I definitely set responseType as `arraybuffer`. But when the onload handler called, `responseType` field was changed as `""`.

I'm not calling any other ``XMLHttpRequest in this code. This is response header I got.

```
accept-ranges:bytes
content-length:102040
content-type:application/octet-stream
date:Fri, 18 Nov 2016 09:30:13 GMT
etag:"582ec3ef-18e98"
last-modified:Fri, 18 Nov 2016 09:03:43 GMT
server:h2o/2.0.4
status:200
```

And this is the request header I sent.

```
:authority:localhost
:method:GET
:path:/gex/t90-01/Duck/Duck.bin
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
accept-language:ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
cache-control:no-cache
pragma:no-cache
referer:https://localhost/gex/
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
```

Anyt help?

Comment: How do you verify the data type? Do you use `typeof`?

Comment: I checked it on inspector. I saw the `response` field was enclosed with `"` so I thought that is string.

Comment: I checked it with `typeof` for in case. But that was actually string.

Comment: @LimeStreem Can you try my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code by changing `setRequestHeader` with `overrideMimeType` as below.

And also, you should handle the `xhr.response` properly inside the `resolve` method you used below and not sure, you have done it correctly.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","THE ADDRESS",true);
xhr.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream");
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function (v) {
    resolve(xhr.response); // xhr.response must be ArrayBuffer but xhr.response is string
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    reject(e);
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer me kindly. But, I need to apologize you because the reason of this problem is completely my problem. I found the library my friend made and that is used in this project is rewrite XMLHttpRequest class. And the rewrrited code injected responseType....However I really thank you to try help me.

Comment: Now glb has its own mime type: xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "model/gltf-binary");